# Which phone service for a rasa voicebot? (or dialogflow)

Tags: python, phone

I am trying to build a telephony voicebot using Rasa. What is the best telephony service I can use?

1. The voicebot would call some users on their direct mobile phone.
2. It would ask some questions to the user and store answers on a database or on Google agenda.

a) I checked some suppliers such as Twilio, Nexmo, but they seem to be focused on **sms rather than voice**.

b) **Or they offer their own integrated service** (with their own speech recognition), like Twilio Autopilot.

c) I noticed I could do everything with DialogFlow, as it also offers Google telephony.

However, I would like to know if this is possible by using a mix of framework and suppliers, **like Rasa / Google voice recognition / Twilio or Skype,** etc.

Does someone have a suggestion of what I could use?